# R Optimization, setting constraint

Tags: r, optimization, solver

I have been solving the optimization problem in `R` with 2 variables using `lpSolveAPI`. "

one of the constraint is `standarddeviation(ax1,bx2)=1.24`.

I am unable to input this constraint, it throws an error message

> "The length of xt must be equal to the number of decision variables in
>   lprec"

Could you please suggest the suitable package in `R` where I would be able to input the above constraint?

Comment: Maybe with `simplex` https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/boot/versions/1.3-20/topics/simplex setting the >= and <= as the same value suits you?

Comment: Have you tried incorporating the constraint in your objective function? As in : `if(sd(ax1,bx2)!=1.24) return Inf`. In this example I assume you're minimizing a function and returning `+Inf` whenever your constraint is not satisfied means the optimization will end up avoiding values which do not satisfy the constraint.

Comment: LPsolve is only for linear problems. Constraints involving a standard deviation (involving the decision variables) are not linear. I don't understand your notation, but this surely looks like a nonlinear constraint. In some cases constraints involving risk can be formulated as a convex quadratic constraint, allowing a wider collection of available solvers.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am able to solve the constraint with solnp algorithm in Rsolnp package . I tried other algorithm in nloptr but solnp throws better solution